# How to tell when an input dialog closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `<input type=color>` element on my page. I want to find out what color is selected and add that color to a div. I have tried:

```
$("#col").on("change",function(){
    var d = $q(this).value;
    $q("#out").innerHTML+="<p>Color: <span style=\"color: "+d+";\">"+d.toUpperCase()+"</span></p>";
});
```

This works perfectly well, ***EXCEPT*** when the user doesn't actually *change* the value of color; I want it to be added *unconditionally* after the user exits the dialog. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `blur` instead of `change` event.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well. It would be great help if you created a fiddle.

Comment: That would be nigh impossible, as it is based on apx. 3000 lines of code--it's a team project, and I'm working on the last phase with a few people.

Comment: Than only take small parts of it.
For example, only take the HTML that surrounds the input in question.